# Opencart Layout and Design

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

Im working on this website [www.theartisanscorner.com.au/index.php](http://www.theartisanscorner.com.au/index.php) and i am very new to Opencart. I have been really trying to work this out, and really need some help

1. The text is too close on all pages in regards to the edge of the pages. I have changed the width of div container, but it just stretches it out.
2. I want to use an image as a border for all pages on the div container on all pages. I can add border-style: solid; but i would like an image instead.

   ## container {

   ```
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FCE3CE;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 980px;
   ```

   }
3. On the homepage slideshow i want to have a border around it (if possible an image border)
4. There is white on the footer images, is this due to the size of the images i have uploaded?

Many thanks,
Deryn

Comment: This is a pretty specific question. If you want these you're going to have to employ a developer to do them for you to be honest

Comment: @Jay I am a developer, but I am new to the opencart infrastructure and functionality. To be honest as well, it defeats the purpose of posting up a question with responses of that nature.

Comment: If you're a developer, you only need to know where the css file is, and can take it from there. The css file is in /catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/stylesheet/ usually named stylesheet.css

Answer (score 0):

> The text is too close on all pages in regards to the edge of the pages. I have changed the width of div container, but it just stretches it out.

You can change `width: 980px;` in /catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/stylesheet/stylesheet.css but as usual it is 980 px because some users have 1024px width in their browsers.

> I want to use an image as a border for all pages on the div container on all pages. I can add border-style: solid; but i would like an image instead.

Use css rule `background-image`.

> On the homepage slideshow i want to have a border around it (if possible an image border)

Yes, it is possible with `background-image`

> There is white on the footer images, is this due to the size of the images i have uploaded?

Maybe it is because you have something after footer? As default there is a message "Powered by Opencart" and due to this message, there is a white space after footer.